# Dictionary data structure in R

Tags: list, r, dictionary, lookup

In R, I have, for example:

```
> foo <- list(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

If I type `foo`, I get:

```
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3
```

How can I look through `foo` to get a list of "keys" only? In this case, (a, b, c).

Answer (score 22):

An R list can have named elements and so function as a dictionary structure.  You can just do:

```
> names(foo)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

If you are looking for a dictionary structure you might also consider using the `hash` packages which provides a Python and Perl like dictionary/hash with the expected functions such as `keys`, so you can say:

```
keys(hash)
```

In terms of performance a list serves as a better dictionary than a hash for several hundred elements or fewer (<200) because of the cost of the hashing. The hash package is much better for very large dictionaries.

Comment: Up vote for giving info on when to use `list` and when to use `hash/dict`.

Answer (score 15):

```
> names(foo)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```