# R, get key from key value (hash)

Tags: r, hash

quick question. My List (in R) looks like:

```
> mylist
$width
[1] 32
```

With mylist[1] I get:

```
$width
[1] 32
```

But how do I get:

```
$width
```

Thanks and cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dictionary data structure in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737194/dictionary-data-structure-in-r)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The names of elements are stored in an *attribute* called "names", which can be accessed via the `names` function.

Try this:

```
mylist <- list(width=42, height=13)
names(mylist)    # "width"  "height"
names(mylist)[1] # "width"

mylist[["width"]] # 42

mylist[sort(names(mylist))] # sort mylist by the names...
```

Answer (score -2):

The $ helps you to extract the value of a key in the list

`mylist = list(width=50, height=100)`

`mylist$width`

would return the value of width in mylist.